# Nodejs Retrieve the GET query string parameters

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, xmlhttprequest

How do I change the code below so I can do this query (http://localhost:3009/api/get-products/?keywords=underwear) ? I've tried every code snippets I could find

```
app.get("/api/get-products/",async (req, res) => {
 client.execute('aliexpress.affiliate.product.query', {
 'app_signature':'maarifahmall',
 // 'category_ids':'111,222,333',
 'fields':'commission_rate,sale_price',
 'keywords':'beauty',
 'max_sale_price':'100',
 'min_sale_price':'15',
 'page_no':'1',
 'page_size':'50',
 'platform_product_type':'ALL',
 'sort':'SALE_PRICE_ASC',
 'target_currency':'USD',
 'target_language':'EN',
 'tracking_id':'maarifahmall',
 'ship_to_country':'US',
 'delivery_days':'3'
  }, 
 function(error, response) {
 if (!error) {
 res.send(response['resp_result']);
 // ['result']['products']['product']
    } else {
 res.send(error);
    }
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how you can pass route parameters:

```
app.get("/api/get-products/:keywords",async (req, res) => {
 client.execute('aliexpress.affiliate.product.query', {
 'app_signature':'maarifahmall',
 // 'category_ids':'111,222,333',
 'fields':'commission_rate,sale_price',
 'keywords':'beauty',
 'max_sale_price':'100',
 'min_sale_price':'15',
 'page_no':'1',
 'page_size':'50',
 'platform_product_type':'ALL',
 'sort':'SALE_PRICE_ASC',
 'target_currency':'USD',
 'target_language':'EN',
 'tracking_id':'maarifahmall',
 'ship_to_country':'US',
 'delivery_days':'3'
  }, 
 function(error, response) {
 if (!error) {
 res.send(response['resp_result']);
 // ['result']['products']['product']
    } else {
 res.send(error);
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: I got "Cannot GET /api/get-products/" in the browser

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how to get the values of the params in your URL than you should use `req.query` this will produce `{ keywords: 'underwear' }`. So you can use `req.query.keywords` to get the value of `keywords`.

btw, your URL is wrong, you have a forward slash before the question mark. the correct URL should be `http://localhost:3009/api/get-products?keywords=underwear`